# Elegant way to deal with vertical and horizontal images in Gatsby

Tags: graphql, gatsby, graphql-js

I'm writing simple Gatsby app that displays photos I'm storing in S3. I'm wondering if there's an elegant way to handle vertical and horizontal photos together.

I'm looking for perhaps something equivalent to the idea of resizing based on the 'long edge' which you can do in some photo editing tools.

Currently, I have two queries and have to combine the two queries elsewhere.

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
query {
verticalImages:allS3Image {
      edges {
        node {
            Url 
            localFile {
              childImageSharp {
                fluid(maxHeight: 900) {
                    ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid  
                }
              }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    horizontalImages:allS3Image {
        edges {
          node {
              Url 
              localFile {
                childImageSharp {
                  fluid(maxWidth: 1200) {
                      ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
                  }
                }
            }
          }
        }
      }
  }
`
```

Comment: Wrong ImageSharp!